# How the Apache Solr server is connecting to drupal db

Tags: solr, drupal-7

Firstly Thanks to stackoverflow which is giving support to everyone.

Iam new to drupal and solr server

I have Successfully installed the solrserver in my system and I can able to search the data using "Apache Solr search module" In drupal7.

But Actually I dont know what is the Background process that is Running.But Inorder to have work with it I need to have a ground knowledge on it.Drupal is connecting to solr server using the url which I have Provided in admin UI.

As Per My knowledge I think the following is the backend flow of Apache solr server module

1)It sends the request of search string from drupal to solr server.

2)The solr server searches for the string and send the result back in the format of json to drupal.

3)Drupal displays the results

**But How the solr server connects to drupal db inorder to search for the string or content?**

Please help with this..I really In a need to know the backend flow how the request is handling

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Drupal specialist, but from the Solr prospective you are searching on the documents previously indexed on Solr. I.e., all documents must be indexed on Solr prior to the search.

Therefore, you have 2 ways here:

1. You call Solr API from your backend and push documents to Solr index. There are specific drupal solutions you may research, but here is the wiki article from Solr prospective describing how to index documents using only JSON API: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON
2. You connect to your database directly from Solr and pull documents to Solr index. Here is the related wiki page: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler